# Convert Jade to EJS

Tags: pug, templating, ejs

Can anyone please help by convert this Jade to EJS?

```
extends layout

block content
    h1.
        User List
    ul
        each user, i in userlist
            li
                a(href="mailto:#{user.email}")= user.username
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no block but an include logic available in EJS. Split up the "main layout" that way that you can include a header and footer (or whatever suits your needs). The iteration is expressed in plain JavaScript escaped in sequences of `<% ... %>`. Using `<%= ... %>` directly outputs the referenced var. Your resulting EJS code might look as follows:

```
<h1>User List</h1>
<ul>
    <% for (var i = 0; i < user.length; i++) { %>
        <li><a href="mailto:<%= user[i].email %>"><%= user[i].username %></a></li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

or, *alternatively*:

```
<h1>User List</h1>
<ul>
    <% user.forEach(function(user) { %>
        <li><a href="mailto:<%= user.email %>"><%= user.username %></a></li>
    <% )} %>
</ul>
```

The include syntax is straight forward:

```
<% include partials/header %>
...
<% include partials/footer %>
```

Note: Include files are located relative to the template with the include statement. Extensions are added automatically. So if your template is stored in let's say `/views`, the full path for the header include would be `/views/partials/header.ejs`.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed a "For In" loop.  Here is what worked for me after tweaking:

```
<h1>User List</h1>
  <ul>
    <% for (var i in userlist){%>
      <li><a href="mailto:<%= userlist[i].email %>"><%= userlist[i].username %></a></li>
    <%} %>

  </ul>
```

Comment: So, that probably means that `userlist` is of type _object_ in your case – and not _array_ (intentionally?). That's not obvious for handling a _list of users_  and left unclear in your original question. Maybe it's best when my answer gets improved with your code as third option for this case (also, we should consider referring to the check on `.hasOwnProperty()`)?

Answer (score -2):

alternatively you can try online convereters from jade to html